# MySQL Join Statement pulling items multiple times from the same field in a DB

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has two columns.  One is `image_id` and one is `image_name`.  Like this

```
image_id | image_name
--------------------
1        | terrier.jpg
2        | schnauzer.jpg
3        | beagle.jpg
```

And I have another table like this:

```
item           |  image_1 | image_2
------------------------------------
Friendly Dogs  |   1      |    2 
Loyal Dogs     |   2      |    3
```

The first table let's call `images` and the second table is `dogs`.

I tried the following SQL but it didn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM dogs INNER JOIN  images ON images.image_id = dogs.image_1 AND INNER JOIN images ON images_image_id = dogs.image_2
```

But this errors out.  I'm missing somethings where I can specify names some kind of alias or something for `image_name` so it doesn't overlap in the query.

What I want is an array that has `image_1` and `image_2` in it rather than `image_name`.

Can someone help out?  Thanks.

I want in the array two arrays or objects:

[item] => Friendly Dogs
[image_1] => terrier.jpg
[image_2] => schnauzer.jpg

and

[item] => Loyal Dogs
[image_1] => schnauzer.jpg
[image_2] => beagle.jpg

Comment: What should be the result table? That should be the best clue for us, because the explanation is not as clear as it should be.

Comment: It'd be great if you could also update your question with "expected output" i.e., how do you want the result to 'look' so to speak...

Comment: Your second table strikes me as a little odd. Why have 2 images? Will you always have 2 and only 2 images for each item, or would you rather have the number of images variable? For instance, maybe you only have 1 image for "Friendly Dogs", but you have 4 images for "Loyal Dogs". Your current structure can't handle that. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes, there will be a set number of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can JOIN a table multiple times:

```
SELECT d.item AS dog, i1.image_name AS im1, i2.image_name AS im2
FROM dogs AS d JOIN images AS i1 ON (i1.image_id = d.image_1)
               JOIN images AS i2 ON (i2.image_id = d.image_2)
```

Comment: I get a resource #66 error when I try to return the results in a print_r

Comment: What happens if you just run the query in MySQL?

Comment: I think it's something to do with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT d.item, i1.image_name image_1, i2.image_name image_2
      FROM dogs d
INNER JOIN images i1 
        ON d.image_1 = i1.image_id
INNER JOIN images i2 
        ON d.image_2 = i2.image_id
```

I am assuming all the dogs will have an image on the `image_1` and `image_2` column.

---

NOTE: The `dogs` table is not in the [First normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). It would be normalized if you created another table to hold the relationships.

**dogs** table

```
dog_id | item           
------------------------
1      | Friendly Dogs  
2      | Loyal Dogs
```

**dogs_images** table

```
dog_id | image_id
-----------------
1      | 1
1      | 2
2      | 2
2      | 3
```

#### Update

The query for the relationship table would be:

```
   SELECT d.dog_id, d.item, i.image_name
     FROM dogs d
LEFT JOIN dogs_images di
       ON d.dog_id = di.dog_id
LEFT JOIN images i
       ON di.image_id = i.image_id
```

The result would be something like:

```
dog_id | item           | image_name   
------------------------------------
1      | Friendly Dogs  | terrier.jpg
1      | Friendly Dogs  | schnauzer.jpg
2      | Loyal Dogs     | schnauzer.jpg
2      | Loyal Dogs     | beagle.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, Shef.  I will take your suggestion.  Does the same SQL as above apply?

Comment: @shummel7845: Nope, that query won't work. You would have to get the relationship records from the `dogs_images` table and calculate the resultset you want in your application logic (PHP, C#, or whatever you are using). Something like this would be returned: `[dog_id] => 1 [item] => Friendly Dogs [image_1] => terrier.jpg`, `[dog_id] => 1 [item] => Friendly Dogs [image_2] => schnauzer.jpg`, `[dog_id] => 2 [item] => Loyal Dogs [image_1] => schnauzer.jpg`, `[dog_id] => 2 [item] => Loyal Dogs [image_1] => beagle.jpg`.

Comment: Can you help me with the SQL I would need using your dogs_images table?